# "Error: no matching function for call distance::distance()" ...Can´t declare an object from a class in main?

Tags: c++, class, oop

Im new at OOP and I keep having this error in this task. Maybe you can help me out.

This right here is the Class header file:

```
class Distance : public Magnitude
{
private:
    double Cantidad;
    char* Unidad;

public:
    Distance(double c, char* u);
    Distance(const Distance& d);

    double getDistance(){return Cantidad;}
    void setDistance(double val) {Cantidad=val;}
    char* getUnidad(){return Unidad;}
    void setUnidad(char* uni) {Unidad=uni;}

    virtual ~Distance();

    Distance& operator =(const Distance & d);
    Distance operator +(const Distance & d);
    Distance operator -(const Distance & d);
    Distance operator *(const Distance & d);
    Distance operator /(const Distance & d);

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &o,const Distance &d);
    friend istream& operator >> (istream &o, Distance &d);
};
```

This over here is the cpp file, where I made the definitions:

```
#include "Distance.h"

Distance::Distance(double c, char* u)
{
    Cantidad=c;
    Unidad=u;
}

Distance::Distance(const Distance& d)
{
 cout << "[***] NumComplejo -> Constructor por copia " << endl;
 Cantidad = d.Cantidad;
 Unidad = d.Unidad;
}

Distance::~Distance()
{
    //dtor
}
```

And finally, this is where the error appears, in main, where I try to declare an object from the class Distance.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

 Distance d1; **/*right here*/**
```

EDIT: 
If I typed: Distance d1=Distance(1231,"CSDVS"); it does work, but I need an empty objet so I can use the overload on >> operator

Comment: I don't see any `Distance` constructor that takes 0 arguments, do you?

Comment: Also, you have not inherited constructors, so a default constructor of `Magnitude` would also be invalid

Comment: I know, and if type:     Distance d1=Distance(1231,"CSDVS"); it does work, but I need an empty objet so I can use the overload on >>

Comment: @user3027470 Provide a default constructor taking zero argumnents then! What's so hard about understanding this requirement??

Comment: If you "need an empty object", you have to manually write a constructor that will properly create "an empty object" (or your idea or "an empty object"). You didn't write it. This is what the compiler is telling you. Without your help, the compiler does not know what "an empty object" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that you are trying to initialize an object with a *default constructor* that you haven't defined.

> [...] but I need an empty objet so I can use the overload on >> operator.

You can do this by simply defining a default constructor:

```
// …
Distance::Distance() 
    : Cantidad(0)
    , Unidad(nullptr) 
    {}
// …
```

You, also, probably want to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for strings.